# Cannot convert Object to Hashtable

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable like below:

```
$hashtable = @{
    "fruit" = "apple"
    "vegetable" = "carrot"
    "foo" = "bar"
    "test01" = "test"
    "test02" = "test"
    "test03" = "test"
    "test04" = "test"
}
```

Now I want to remove entries like 'Test' and create a **new** hashtable:

```
[hashtable]$newHashTable = $hashtable.GetEnumerator() | `
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "test*"}
```

This returns the error: `Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".`

How can I create a new hashtable from the filtered output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a smarter way to do this, but the following works:

```
$newhashtable = @{}
$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "test*"} | ForEach-Object { $newhashtable[$_.name] = $_.value }
```

You can see `$newhashtable` is preserved as a Hastable:

```
PS> $newhashtable.gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `Remove` method having got a list of the keys you want to remove from the hashtable:

```
$hashtable = @{
    "fruit" = "apple"
    "vegetable" = "carrot"
    "foo" = "bar"
    "test01" = "test"
    "test02" = "test"
    "test03" = "test"
    "test04" = "test"
}

$newHashtable = $hashtable.Clone()
$RemoveKeys = $newHashtable.keys | Where-Object { $_ -like 'test*' }

ForEach ($Key in $RemoveKeys) { $newHashtable.Remove($Key)}
```

Note that you need to use `Clone()` if you want to create a copy of the hashtable to modify as just using `=` creates a reference and the original `$hashtable` object would also be modified.